# My sticky sidebar does not show until the user scrolls down

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like the title says, I got the sticky sidebar to work. The only concern is that when the user first get to the page,  the sidebar does not show at all until the user scrolls down, then it does go up and down. I was wondering if there's something wrong with the JS code or something else..? I can't seem to get it to work >-<

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

        var $sticky = $('.sidebar');
        var $stickyrStopper = $('.sticky-stopper');
        if (!!$sticky.offset()) { 

        var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
        var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
        var stickOffset = 0;
        var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
        var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
        var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;

        $(window).scroll(function(){ 
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 

            if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
                $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff });
            } else if (stickyTop < windowTop+stickOffset) {
                $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset });
            } else {
                $sticky.css({position: 'fixed', top: 'initial'});
            }
            });
            }
            });
        </script>
```

There's nothing specific in the CSS or the html. Just a div on the right side `class: sidebar` and no specific CSS either except for the design of it. I thought there'd be a lot of code so I didn't post it here. Let me know if you do need it..

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<div class="sidebar">
        <!-- Office Reservation -->
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl_In_Out" runat="server">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                <!--<div class="container col-md-3" style="margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top:0px">-->
                <%--<div class="" style="margin-left: 10px; padding-left:0px; max-width: 240px; width: 100%; position: relative; float: left;">--%>
                <div class="office-reservation">
                    <div class="panel-main panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center" style="font-size: 15px; color: #444; font-weight: bold;">OFFICE RESERVATION</div>
                        <hr style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px;">
                        <%--<div class="divider-line" style="width: 90px; border-top: 1px solid #ddd; text-align: center; margin: 0px 50px 0px 70px;"></div>--%>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: left">
                                    <label class="control-label" style="padding-left: 20px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #444;"><b>In</b></label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="textarea-form">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchDateFrom" CssClass="form-control form-control-inline input-small date-picker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="padding: 3px;"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_SearchTimeFrom" CssClass="form-control text-right" Width="145" Height="35" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" style="padding: 3px; width: 20px"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: left">
                                    <label class="control-label" style="padding-left: 20px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #444;"><b>Out</b></label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchDateTo" CssClass="form-control form-control-inline input-small date-picker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="padding: 3px"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchTimeTo" CssClass="form-control timepicker timepicker-no-seconds" Width="145" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_SearchTimeTo" CssClass="form-control" Width="145" Height="35" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" style="padding: 3px; width:20px"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="wigdet_input_box" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Reserve" runat="server" Text="RESERVE" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Width="50%" OnClick="btn_Reserve_Time_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </asp:Panel>

            <!-- QUICK CONTACT FORM -->
            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_Question" runat="server">
                <!--<div class="container col-md-3" style="margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top:0px">-->
                <%--<div class="" style="margin-left: 10px; padding-left:0px; max-width: 240px; width: 100%; position: relative; float: left;">--%>
                <div class="sidebar-sticky2">
                    <div class="panel-main panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center" style="font-size: 15px; color: #444; font-weight: bold;">QUESTIONS ?</div>
                        <hr style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: left">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Email" CssClass="form-control" Width="145" Font-Size="Small" runat="server" placeholder="Email Address"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="padding: 3px"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Message" TextMode="multiline" Rows="3" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="form-control" class="contact-message" Style="width: 100%!important; height: 70px; resize: none;" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Message"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="wigdet_input_box" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Message_Send" runat="server" Text="SEND" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Width="50%" OnClick="btn_Message_Send_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>

            <!-- CONTACT INFORMATION -->
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <!--<div class="container col-md-3" style="margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top:0px">-->
                <%--<div class="" style="margin-left: 10px; padding-left:0px; max-width: 240px; width: 100%; position: relative; float: left;">--%>
                <div class="sidebar-sticky3">
                    <div class="panel-main panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center" style="font-size: 15px; color: #444; font-weight: bold;">AGENT INFORMATION</div>
                        <hr style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel-body"">
                            <%--<div class="agent-photo">
                                <img src="/images/agent_face.jpg" width="80" alt="Agent" style="float: left;" />
                            </div>--%>
                            <div class="contact-info" style="text-align: center; color: #444; font-size: 14px;">
                                <%--<img src="/images/agent_face.jpg" width="150" alt="Agent" />--%>
                                <h5>Contact Number: </h5><asp:Label ID="lbl_ListingContactPhone" runat="server" Text="none"></asp:Label>
                                <h5>E-mail Address: </h5><asp:Label ID="lbl_ListingContactEmail" runat="server" Text="none"></asp:Label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.sidebar {
            float: right;
            width: 245px;
            margin-left: 850px;
        }

        .sidebar-sticky {
            float: right;
        }

        .sidebar-sticky2 {
            float: right;
        }

        .sidebar-sticky3 {
            float: right;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it would be useful to have the HTML and CSS. Try to reduce it to the minimum amount necessary (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) . Your issue could be related to the CSS attribute `position` of the `$('.sidebar')` element.

Comment: @David Thank you! I've updated it as best as I could

Comment: That's way too much code :) , try to reduce it please. And where is the `.sticky-stopper` class? You are trying to get the `offset` from one element with that class but there is no one.

Comment: @David Sorry about that. The sticky-stopper div is actually right after the last div "sidebar-sticky3".

Answer (score 0):

Since the picture is not clear enough to reproduce the issue you described, I would only just point out aspects I observed to be out of place in the script you posted.

I have not studied the logic of the code enough to establish its correctness or a possible lack of it. But I believe some of the variables at play in the script ought to be evaluated during scroll since a change in the page content can invalidate their initial state:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // 1. These variables factor in statically to the feature
  // and it's appropriate that they are evaluated once
  var $sticky = $('.sidebar');
  var $stickyrStopper = $('.sticky-stopper');

  if (!$sticky.offset()) {
    return;
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var stickOffset = 0;

    // 2. These variables factor in DYNAMICALLY to the feature,
    // and they must be re-evaluated in alignment with 
    // changing content for instance.
    // --
    // Therefore they deserve to be evaluated inside the scroll handler.
    var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
    var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
    var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
    var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
    var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;

    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
      $sticky.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: diff
      });
    } else if (stickyTop < windowTop + stickOffset) {
      $sticky.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: stickOffset
      });
    } else {
      $sticky.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 'initial'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

See if that provides you a stepping stone.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I got it to work without JavaScript. I just used position:sticky instead and it reduces the code too